# Implementing pseudocode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I'm trying to implement my code in pseudocode in JavaScript, however I'm not getting the result that I'm supposed to. I want the function to permute the elements of the array p places to the left. In pseudocode I'm using a queue data structure, but I thought I can as well us an array. As the result of my function, I get an array with [2, 2, 2, 2]. Can you please help me out?

My code in **pseudocode**:

```
Function PERMUTEVECTOR(row, p)

    If p=0 then

        Return row

    End if

    New Queue q

    For 0<= i <4 do

        ENQUEUE[row[i], q]

    End for

 

    For 1<= i <= p do

        ENQUEUE[HEAD[q],q]

        DEQUEUE[q]

    End for

 

    For 0<=i<4 do

        Row[i] <- HEAD[q]

        DEQUEUE[q]

    End for

    Return row

End function
```

My code in **JavaScript**:

```
function permute_vector(row, p)

{

  if (p=0)

  {return row}

   

  let q = new Array()

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)

  {

    q.push(row[i])

  }

 

for (i=0; i<p; i++)

  {

    q.push(q[0])

    q.pop()

  }

 

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)

  {

    row[i] = q[0]

    q.pop()

  }

return row

}

 

px = permute_vector([2,4,1,3], 1)

console.log("px is:", px)

}
```

I did the same in **Python** and it works fine:

```
def permute_vector(row, p):

  if p==0:

    return row

  q = []

  for i in range(4):

    q.append(row[i])

  

  for i in range(p):

    q.append(q[0])

    q.pop(0)

  for i in range(4):

    row[i] = q[0]

    q.pop(0) 

  return row
```

What am I doing wrong **with my JavaScript code**?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of all these line-feeds, besides having to scroll?

Comment: please add the wanted result. `=` is an assignment and in `if` ususally wrong ...

Comment: programmers are not paid by the line - please make code readable

Comment: `As the result of my function, I get an array with [2, 2, 2, 2]` is that correct?

Comment: just use `q.shift()` method instead of `pop`

Comment: all that just to do `const q = row.slice(); while(p-- > 0) q.push(q.shift()); return q;`? or `row.push(...row.splice(0, p)); return row;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, Array.pop() removes the last element. You need Array.shift() for removing the first one.

```js
function permute_vector(row, p)

{

  if (p===0) // in js, checks are with == (loose) or === (strict).
             // = is for assignment and you were assigning p to 0 here.

  {return row}

   

  let q = new Array()

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)

  {

    q.push(row[i])

  }

 

for (i=0; i<p; i++)

  {

    q.push(q[0])

    q.shift() // shift instead of pop

  }

 

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)

  {

    row[i] = q[0]

    q.shift() // shift instead of pop

  }

return row

}

 

px = permute_vector([2,4,1,3], 1)

console.log("px is:", px)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes:

- Comparisons need double or triple equal signs. In fact, you should prefer triple equal signs as you can read in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).
- In python [`pop()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop) accepts an index to remove a specific item. You're making use of that to remove the first item. In JavaScript [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) merely is capable of removing the last item. Use [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first item.

Working code:

```js
function permute_vector(row, p) {
  if (p === 0) {
    return row;
  }
  let q = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    q.push(row[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    q.push(q[0]);

    q.shift();
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    row[i] = q[0];

    q.shift();
  }
  return row;
}

px = permute_vector([2, 4, 1, 3], 1);

console.log("px is:", px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now when you've got it, you can just ditch the whole thing and replace it with

```
vec[n:] + vec[:n] (Python)

[...vec.slice(n), ...vec.slice(0, n)]  (JS)
```

Basic textbook algorithms are rarely useful in scripting languages, because they implement stuff like this out of the box.